# Which version of Socket.IO am I running?

Tags: node.js, npm, socket.io

Recently, I installed a new version of Socket.IO with npm. I tried using `npm update socket.io`, but that didn't seem to work for me because when I checked the version using `npm list socket.io`, it didn't show as a new version. So, I just used `npm install socket.io`, which seemed to work, because if I now go to Command Prompt, and enter the command `npm list socket.io`, I get this:

[image: Command Prompt Screenshot]

Brackets is my code editor, and this seems to indicate that it has its own installation of Socket.IO. is this a correct assumption? Anyway, before installing the new version of Socket.IO, the part saying `socket.io@2.2.0` wasn't there.

So how do I know which one I'm running? I think it *should* be 2.2.0, but before installing it, because there was only the 1.1.0 version there, so I must've been originally running that.

By the way, what does extraneous mean in this sense? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command, it will tell you the version which is currently being used for the project:

`node -p "require('./package.json').version"`

And also, it looks like you have a package.json file in brackets directory. I have no idea why. Maybe, it was installed as a part of dependency or it is a dependency.

But if you working in that **directory/path**, i.e., 
`C:\Users\William\node_modules\brackets`, **socket.io** will use *version 1.1*, otherwise for any other **directory/path** it will use the *version 2.2*.

I hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: Ok, I'm definitely not working in that directory, so I should be running Socket.IO 2.2.0. Thanks for the explanation!